# Graphics.DrawPolygon to draw a hexagon?

Tags: .net, graphics

I am working with some simple code to draw a hexagon and I am getting unexpected results.

Code follows:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim bm As New Bitmap(640, 480)
Dim bmg As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)
Dim sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DrawHex(80, 50)
End Sub

Public Sub DrawHex(x As Integer, y As Integer)

    Dim side As Integer = 25  '' the length of the side of a hex

    Dim ShortSide As Single = Convert.ToSingle(System.Math.Sin(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * side)
    Dim LongSide As Single = Convert.ToSingle(System.Math.Cos(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * side)

    Dim Points(6) As PointF
    Points(0) = New PointF(x, y)
    Points(1) = New PointF(x + side, y)
    Points(2) = New PointF(x + side + ShortSide, y + LongSide)
    Points(3) = New PointF(x + side, y + LongSide + LongSide)
    Points(4) = New PointF(x, y + LongSide + LongSide)
    Points(5) = New PointF(x - ShortSide, y + LongSide)
    bmg.DrawPolygon(p, Points)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, New Point(10, 10))

End Sub
```

End Class

Five points of the hexagon are fine.  It's the last point that isn't drawing correctly and I don't understand why:

[image]

"ShortSide" and "LongSide" represent the lines of right triangles that are outside the hexagon.  I'm pretty sure that the mathematics are right and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thank you!

Comment: Does that last point move if you modify the point in `e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, New Point(10, 10))`?

Comment: It does not.  The figure is the same as above, but drawn in a different location on the form.

Comment: I thought as much.  Lars has your answer.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are zero based.  Change it to:

```
Dim Points(5) As PointF
```

will get you six points.  Your last point (#7) was defaulting to (0, 0).

Comment: I knew getting more eyes on this would be the right approach.  Thank you, LarsTech!